# Blocking of LTS upgrade

Tags: upgrade

I would like to upgrade LTS16.04 to LTS 18.04 but an unuseable but installed package seems to be blocking this. How do I get rid of this blockage without a new installation.

Comment: I think we would like to say the specific error and if possible the name of the package.

Comment: Knowing which package was the problem. With the latest try I found that the responsible package was mentioned. Previous try did not show this. Removing it, solved the blockage.